# 20.04 Server Hangs on Reboot

Tags: server, 20.04, shutdown, systemd

I'm running into an issue when trying to reboot or shutdown my primary storage server at home. The shutdown process unmounts and stops most of the system until it hits `systemd-udevd`, then it hangs.

This what's displayed on the monitor:

```
...
[  OK  ] Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
[  OK  ] Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[  OK  ] Reached target Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Reached target Final Step.
[  OK  ] Finished Reboot.
[  OK  ] Reached target Reboot.
[2706010.062757] systems-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: systemd-udevd, systemd-udevd
[2706100.061724] systems-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: systemd-udevd
[2706190.199550] shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: systemd-udevd
[2706280.198498] shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: systemd-udevd
[2706360.222337] sd-umoun[120154]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
[2706360.223343] sd-umoun[120155]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
[2706360.224401] sd-umoun[120156]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
[2706360.229444] shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize  file systems, ignoring
```

At this point the system just sits there until I physically restart the machine.

This is an excerpt from `/var/log/syslog` that takes place around the time of the hang:

```
May  6 07:33:22 ubuntu-store systemd[1]: Stopped Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
May  6 07:33:22 ubuntu-store systemd[1]: Stopping LVM event activation on device 8:16...
May  6 07:33:22 ubuntu-store systemd[1]: Stopping LVM event activation on device 8:32...
May  6 07:33:22 ubuntu-store systemd[1]: Stopping LVM event activation on device 8:48...
May  6 07:33:22 ubuntu-store systemd[1]: Stopping LVM event activation on device 8:64...
May  6 07:33:22 ubuntu-store systemd[1]: Stopping LVM event activation on device 8:80...
May  6 07:33:22 ubuntu-store systemd[1]: Stopping Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
May  6 07:33:22 ubuntu-store systemd[1]: Stopping PackageKit Daemon...
May  6 07:33:22 ubuntu-store systemd[1]: Stopping Authorization Manager...
May  6 08:05:50 ubuntu-store systemd-sysctl[433]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
May  6 08:05:50 ubuntu-store systemd-sysctl[433]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/default/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
```

The machine was manually restarted at `08:05:50`.

A bit about the system:

- Ubuntu Server 20.04 with all updates
- Runs as a dedicated Samba server
- 5th-Gen Intel Core i5 w/16GB RAM
- 250GB SSD boot drive
- 25TB ZFS storage pool

`lsb_release` shows:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

While `uname -r` shows:

```
5.4.0-72-generic
```

The issue has only recently been observed (last month or so), as it doesn't get shut down very often unless there are security updates that require a reboot. One anomaly that I have yet to trace down is a load inconsistency. The CPU utilisation rarely exceeds 4%. The RAM usage rarely exceeds 9GB. The swap file, when used, might be a few dozen megabytes at most. The load, however, sits around 2.2. Running `htop` or `glances` does not reveal anything out of the ordinary. Not sure if this is evidence of a zombie process that isn't identified as such by the system.

As one would expect, rebooting the system returns everything to normal for a couple of days. However, as this is a server, I am not enamoured with the idea of having the machine reboot itself every Sunday night as though it were a Windows desktop from the 90s.

Any ideas on what might be causing the issue and/or how I might resolve it?

Comment: is it a possibility of booting a previous kernel image?

Comment: @jad unlikely. I've updated the question to include the output of `lsb_release -a` as well as `uname -r`. This was something that I thought as well, given the `/oldboot` references, but the kernel was always the most current 

Comment: the usual google results appear to be from a bad driver update ... booting to a previous kernel version might allow you to undo the updates, which is all I was suggesting.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. It's certainly an option 

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I had to complete re write the ubuntu server on my sd card so that I could run it again. (I was working on raspberry pi 4 8gb RAM).

After I reproduced the error, I found that the a partition named writable.
I saw that the partition was just gone just cause I rebooted the server.

As a temporary fix you could recreate that partition as writable and select the partition system as ext4 (linux file system).